# Response surface Analysis.Analysis of Variation using MATLAB

Tags: manova

How can I do Analysis of variation(ANOVA) and Response surface analysis for two factors on a **3 dimensional(17x3) input** and corresponding **17x1 output  data** using MATLAB? If i could get required codes in MATLAB,it would be quite better.

Comment: This could be more appropriate for SO.